# How do I get the first and second closest datetime in date by a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to create a new df that takes both the most recent date and the second most recent date for each store in the Date Time column; however, not all stores have a previous visit dates so some may need to return Nan.

df

| Store | Date Time |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-03-24 19:04:00 |
| 100 | 2022-05-05 10:29:00 |
| 100 | 2022-07-29 11:58:00 |
| 101 | 2022-03-15 08:56:00 |
| 102 | 2022-04-15 10:21:00 |

Resulting new df:

| Store | Previous Visit Date | Most Recent Visit Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-05-05 10:29:00 | 2022-07-29 11:58:00 |
| 101 | Nan | 2022-03-15 08:56:00 |
| 102 | Nan | 2022-04-15 10:21:00 |

I tried first to sort values by store than index.
df = df.set_index('Store').sort_values(['Store', 'Date Time'])

I don't know how to integrate if store is unique take Most Recent Visit Date, if it has multiple entries pick the closet date = df['Most Recent Visit Date'] , and 2nd closest visit date = df['Previous Visit Date'].
I might be making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby()` with `shift()` here:
`(df.pipe(lambda d: d.set_index('Store')).groupby('Store')['Date Time'].shift().rename('Previous Visit Date') )` 
The `pipe` step is just to set the index so we can `groupby` by store. This

```
Store
100           NaT
100    2022-03-24
100    2022-05-05
101    2022-03-15
102    2022-04-15
Name: Previous Visit Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So, you can easily add this as a column in your original df.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the dataframe by `store`, then sort the Date Time values for each group, and take the most recent and second recent values for the timestamp:

```py
(
    df
    .groupby('Store')['Date Time']
    .agg(lambda x: dict(zip(['Most Recent Visit Date', 'Previous Visit Date'],
                            x.sort_values(ascending=False)[:2])))
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .reset_index()
)
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
   Store Most Recent Visit Date Previous Visit Date
0    100    2022-07-29 11:58:00 2022-05-05 10:29:00
1    101    2022-03-15 08:56:00                 NaT
2    102    2022-04-15 10:21:00                 NaT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the dataframe by `Date Time` ascending first then group by `Store` column to get the last two recent dates.

```py
df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'])
df = df.sort_values(['Store', 'Date Time'])

out = (df.set_index(df.groupby('Store').cumcount(ascending=False))
       .groupby('Store')
       .apply(lambda g: g['Date Time'].iloc[-2:])
       .unstack().reset_index()
       .rename(columns={0: 'Most Recent Visit Date', 1: 'Previous Visit Date'}))
```

```
print(df)

   Store           Date Time
0    100 2022-03-24 19:04:00
1    100 2022-05-05 10:29:00
2    100 2022-07-29 11:58:00
3    101 2022-03-15 08:56:00
4    102 2022-04-15 10:21:00

print(out)

   Store Most Recent Visit Date Previous Visit Date
0    100    2022-07-29 11:58:00 2022-05-05 10:29:00
1    101    2022-03-15 08:56:00                 NaT
2    102    2022-04-15 10:21:00                 NaT
```